# PHP Generate numircal sequence starting from 1 within for each loop

Tags: php, foreach

So I have a table which is generated by a foreach loop. Within the table the id is used to load a modal. I wonder how I can generate a numircal sequence starting from 1, then 2, 3 and so on. I am aware that I can use http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php for this, but I don´t know how to use is within the existing loop? I have market the placement within the code with ????

The reason I want to do this is to add some structure for the reader, it will have no other function.

code:

```
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
    <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Fråga:</th>
          </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php foreach ($modals as $key => $title) { ?>
        <tr>
          <td><?php ???? ?></td>
          <td><a href="#cptmodal_<?php echo $title['id']; ?>" data-toggle="modal"><?php echo $title['title'];?></a></td>
        </tr>
        <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 5):

I think this is what you are looking for. There are tons of ways to do it though.

```
<?php $i = 0; ?>
<?php foreach ($modals as $key => $title): ?>
    <?php $i++; ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $i; ?></td>
        <td><a href="#cptmodal_<?php echo $title['id']; ?>" data-toggle="modal"><?php echo $title['title'];?></a></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Edit: You do not use the `$key` at all, you can just use a `for` loop, makes for cleaner code.

```
 <?php for($i = 0; $i < count($modals); $i++): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $i; ?></td>
        <td><a href="#cptmodal_<?php echo $modals[$i]['id']; ?>" data-toggle="modal"><?php echo $modals[$i]['title'];?></a></td>
    </tr>
<?php endfor; ?>
```

EDIT: Depending on the structure of your array you can use the `$key`; ie. if it looks like this:

```
$modals = array(
    0 => array('id' => $id, 'title' => $title),
    1 => array('id' => $id, 'title' => $title),
    2 => array('id' => $id, 'title' => $title),
);

<?php foreach ($modals as $key => $title): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $key + 1; /* Note the +1 here (arrays start from 0) */ ?></td>
        <td><a href="#cptmodal_<?php echo $title['id']; ?>" data-toggle="modal"><?php echo $title['title'];?></a></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: that is exactly what I am looking for! I am not using key and will look in to revising the code! Thank you very much for the quick response!

Comment: See updated answer for another way that just came to mind. :P

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php int $i = 1; foreach ($modals as $key => $title) { ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo($i); $i++; ?></td>
      <td><a href="#cptmodal_<?php echo $title['id']; ?>" data-toggle="modal"><?php echo $title['title'];?></a></td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
```